# Grouping MySQL results

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM members_family_view ORDER BY `agelastsept` ASC
```

Which returns the following results:

[image]

I want to be able to change the data returned for display purposes so that instead of agelastsept displaying 7 it would display U8's, 8 would display U9's, 10 would display U11's, 11 would display U12's, 12 would display U13's and 13 would display U14's.

Is this possible in a MySQL query?

Comment: While @sashkello's answer below is perfectly valid, I'd like to point out that 'displaying' is never a database's task. You should format this in the application, not the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this query

```
select concat('U', (id+1), '\'s') as Name, total from tbl
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c38/2)**:

```
| NAME | TOTAL |
----------------
| U2's |    50 |
| U3's |    55 |
| U4's |    89 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to concatenate:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT("U", agelastsept + 1, "'s") AS 'agelastsept',
    total
FROM members_family_view 
ORDER BY `agelastsept` ASC
```

Comment: `CONCAT("U", agelastsept + 1 , "'s")` actually.

Comment: Don't think so, as the delimiter is a double quote in this case. Officially SQL doesn't even support the double quote however for strings, so no clue how MySQL handles this.

Comment: @sashkello. Thanks for the response. This doesn't quite work as the agelastsept for some who is 8 would be U9's - so, it's plus 1 year.

Comment: Edited, it should work now. Thanks for comments. And yes, I checked "'s" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select CONCAT("U", (agelastsept + 1 ), "'s")  as agelastsept,total FROM members_family_view ORDER BY `agelastsept` ASC
```